# Confusion about `Element.prototype.scrollTo`

Tags: javascript

I've always used `window.scrollTo` and never knew about `Element.prototype.scrollTo`. I am surprised by the discovery that it exists for `Element` too and works just fine.

But I tried looking for its documentation and couldn't find. My question is, should I safely use it without having to worry about browser quirks? Is there a documentation available for it? Or I should assume `window.scrollTo` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) applies to `Element.prototype.scrollTo` as well?

I am doing

```
document.querySelector('.my-div').scrollTo({
    left: 10,
    top: 100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

Will this syntax support in all browsers? Including smooth scrolling?

Comment: Not sure. It is supported by Firefox and Chrome but not by IE. You can add a check `Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('scrollTo')`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a non-standard method and is for example not supported in Internet Explorer 11.

[image: IE11 Console output]

I wouldn't recommend using it if you need to support many different browsers.

Comment: There's this [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) available which works fine. I'm more curious to find out if it has any documentation anywhere! I tried on Chrome, FF, Opera on Mac and it works natively, I can go ahead with the current setup because polyfill will do what needs to be done.

Still, it'd be better if I can find any documentation. Even if it is non-standard feature.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is now updated. You can find it here with Window.scrollTo and Element.scrollTo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions

IE and the old edge(not chromium based) don't seem to support it.